# How to avoid telling people when it is your birthday?

Tags: birthdays

I really dislike celebrating my birthday and would prefer to keep that information private.

Usually when asked this question I change the subject or give a vague answer such as: "In a couple of months". However this does not work, if someone insists on knowing. How can I politely decline answering that question without sounding like I do not trust or like them and making sure they will stop bringing it up?

**My goal:** Avoid telling people when my birthday is and making sure they stop asking.

Comment: What's wrong with just saying "I don't celebrate my birthday and don't want to share when it is."?

Comment: What country and culture is it?

Comment: I think it could also help to include some context. For example, over here in some offices it's usual for people to celebrate their birthday by bringing treats for your coworkers. If I were eating the pie someone else brought, and then told someone asking 'when is your birthday' that I won't tell them as I don't celebrate, I'd be seen as rude and probably also as a cheapskate. But if someone were asking me randomly online, declining to share personally identifying information is way more easy and less easily seen as rude. So, in what kind of situation are you usually asked these questions?